# Confirmation Box with ok as hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my problem: chrome does not allow new tab to be opened without involvement of user action( it opens a new window instead which I do not want), so to tackle that I want the new page to be opened when user clicks ok in confirm box.
unfortunately, `bool= window.confirm('sure?')` does not count as user action, so I need a simple code, which would look like normal confirmation box, but instead of ok button, there would be an anchor whose url i can set dynamically.

P.S : I believe it can be done using JQuery-UI, but I want to do it just using javascript and JQuery, this is targeting chrome browser only( that's my only silver lining).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a [modal](http://codegeekz.com/jquery-modal-plugins/) It looks like a Confirm box but is created by you and you can style it.

Comment: I am trying to do it without plug-in, do you any place that provides sample code for such a thing?

Comment: Google is your friend

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
window.open("your url","_blank");
}
```

if i got what you actually need, You can use simple js.

Comment: sorry mate, i have already tried this, chrome does not consider this as an user action, if i am correct, user action has to be a direct callback.